# Why does Pressure Increase the Tc (Critical Temperature) of a Superconductor?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity

*Just a heads up - please make this answer understandable to around 1st year degree level physics - not PhD research. So I can understand it - thanks.*

I was wondering why they Critical Temperature (Tc) of a Superconductor will increase as the pressure of the superconductor increases. Has it got anything to do with reduced lattice vibrations OR the changes to the Vortex Lattice - and if so why / how?

Comment: My related question about a temperature-pressure plot: [446905](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/446905/temperature-pressure-plot-for-superconducting-records).