# Temperature-pressure plot for superconducting records?

Tags: pressure, temperature, superconductivity

Eremets et al. ([arXiv:1812.01561](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.01561), [*Nature* **569**, 528–531 (2019)](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1201-8)) and Hemley et al. ([arXiv1808.07695](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.07695), [*PRL* **122**, 027001 (2019)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.122.027001)) have reported new high-temperature record for superconductivity, as covered by [MIT Tech Review](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/612559/the-record-for-high-temperature-superconductivity-has-been-smashed-again/?fbclid=IwAR34f1utawOj3gy7UI4S-QavcQPiszo79G0jDzbK9qjaPqRm1AhSvtPwOAU) and [Physics Today](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/do/10.1063/PT.6.1.20180823b/full/?fbclid=IwAR0f0pu--HxiDa2h22qG7h7lNPjMeU5U6NIgyokSx2y1AbE_dJlcp_5Cqns).  Not surprisingly in light of recent trends, the very high temperatures of **250 K** and **260 K** is only achieved at the very high pressures of **170 GPa** and **200 GPa**, respectively. (Edit: Room-temperature (**288 K**) superconductivity has now been achieved at **267 GPa**: *[Nature* 586, 373–377 (2020)](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-020-2801-z)
, covered in [*Quanta*](https://www.quantamagazine.org/physicists-discover-first-room-temperature-superconductor-20201014/). Edit #2: Now retracted.)

I have heard it said that, although record temperatures have been increasing, the temperature-pressure "possibility frontier" is basically unchanged.  (See [Production possibility frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production%E2%80%93possibility_frontier)
for the analogous economics concept.)

**Question**: Does anyone have a plot of the superconducting records for temperature vs. pressure?

Here are some plots of record temperature vs. time that contain some pressure information, which may allow someone to construct such a plot: [1](https://phys.org/news/2016-08-unraveling-crystal-high-temperature-superconductor.html), [2](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature14165), [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Timeline_of_Superconductivity_from_1900_to_2015.svg), [4](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Which_superconductor_material_experimentally_achieved_has_highest_Tc).  I do not know if it's safe to assume that all records without an explicitly noted pressure were performed at atmospheric pressure. #3 is Wikipedia:

[image]

(I would also love to know what's responsible for this phenomenon -- [previously asked here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146719/) -- but I think a plot is a good first step.)

Comment: It took me longer than I'd like to admit to figure out that both the horizontal and vertical axes in your plot have non-uniform spacing --- I think it's the uniformly-spaced grid lines that tricked me. If anyone reading this question starts to prepare such a plot on their own, a less-sneaky data presentation technique would be a nice thing to keep in mind.

Comment: @rob, it is not his plot. As he wrote correctly, it is from Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Timeline_of_Superconductivity_from_1900_to_2015.svg

Comment: You can find Tc VS pressure graphs for a different class of superconductors in this review:  
https://arxiv.org/ftp/cond-mat/papers/0410/0410367.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This [Science news article](https://www.science.org/content/article/thanks-bit-diamond-smashing-practical-room-temperature-superconductivity-could-be-close) (August 2021) on the criticism of the recent high-temp superconductor claims features a plot like this, although it has no year information, no normal-pressure points, and is only sporadically labeled.

[image]